# How To Fetch All Available JSON Data inside a index of JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch the name and price from JSON data as shown below but it only gives me one name and one price as I have to use the index to fetch a particular data how can I fetch all the available name and price from the JSON data

here is my function

```
void getData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(
    "API LINK");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  String data = response.body;

  var decodeData = jsonDecode(data);

  var name = decodeData['entry'][0]['gsx\$name'];
  var price = decodeData['entry'][0]['gsx\$price'];

  print(name);
  print(price);
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: you turned it into a map. You can still use a for loop or forEach to iterate over all the data inside it.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use a for loop

```dart
for(var i = 0; i < decodeData['entry'].length; i++){
  print(decodeData['entry'][i]['gsx\$name']);
  print(decodeData['entry'][i]['gsx\$price']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decodeData.forEach((key,value){
    print(value['gsx\$name']); 
    print(value['gsx\$price']);
})
```

This can help.